# Room mailboxes without exchange

Tags: exchange

I would like to implement a software similar to what exchange does with room mailboxes.

Currently we dont own an exchange implementation and at the short therm this is a necessity...

Anyone knows a software to manage this kind of equipment?

Comment: What does Exchange "do with room mailboxes"? In other words, what do you want to do?

Comment: make some kind of reservation of the room...

Answer (score 2):

Some simple variant: http://mrbs.sourceforge.net/